# Align text by character in iOS 7

Tags: ios, text, alignment

I have a UITextView in which is loaded some text. But I need to align the text by character without having the user to play with spaces to align the text. This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Do you mean text justify ? If so try this : 
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

Comment: No, text justify doesn't work. I updated my question with image.

Comment: You should show a bit of research behind the topic, or most users won't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to achieve this, would be to have two UITextView next to each other. You would set the alignement like this :

```
leftTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
rightTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```